# I wouldn't go on a steamboat because I get seasick in the water/on the float/off shore/on the open sea

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I wouldn't go on a steamboat because I get seasick in the water/on the
> float/off shore/on the open sea

Is it correct to say '**in the water**' in this sentence?

Which option sounds better, **on the float/off shore/on the open sea**?

Answer (score 2):

If you *always* get seasick when on any type of (large) watercraft, you could just say "I get seasick [easily]."

If you're okay on a canoe, or motorboat, or maybe a ferry, but being on a large craft in the open ocean is a problem, "I get seasick on the open ocean" or "I get seasick over deep water" would work.

"In the water" doesn't make sense in this context (that would imply you yourself are literally **in** the water, i.e. swimming) and "on the float" is not idiomatic in American English. "Off shore" could work but the options above are more commonly used in relation to oceangoing vessels; "off shore" is more often used as a descriptor for a more fixed structure like "off-shore wind farm" or "off-shore drilling platform."

Comment: The same applies to British English. (_Steamboat_ sounds old-fashioned unless the ship really is steam-powered.)

Comment: @KateBunting - once aboard the lugger...

Comment: Thank you, Randomhead. How about 'on the open sea'?

Comment: @i_yre_b that would work as well, and is actually even more common [according to Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+open+sea%2Con+the+open+ocean&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20open%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20open%20ocean%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20the%20open%20sea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20open%20ocean%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thank you, @randomhead